# Facing issue with PHP Excel Export/Import

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to export record from db to excel using PHP (Codeignitor) and then Import the same excel file again using PHP (Codignitor)

**Export Code IS:**

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . date('d-m-Y') . '.xls');

$export .= '<table border="1">';
$export .= '<tr>';
$export .= '<td>Gate Name</td>';
$export .= '<td>ID</td>';
$export .= '<td>Name</td>';
$export .= '<td>Rank</td>';
$export .= '<td>Time</td>';
$export .= '<td>Entry Type</td>';
$export .= '<td>Work Place</td>';
$export .= '<td>Car Type</td>';
$export .= '<td>Car Number</td>';
$export .= '<td>Inspector Name</td>';
$export .= '</tr>';
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $export .= '<tr>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->gate_name . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->soldier_id . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->soldier_name . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->soldier_rank . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->time . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->entry_type . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->work_place . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->vehicle_type . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->vehicle_number . '</td>';
    $export .= '<td>' . $row->inspector_name . '</td>';
    $export .= '</tr>';
}
$export .= '</table>';
echo $export;
```

When I try to emport the downloaded file using  [This PHP Library - SimpleXLSX](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6279-PHP-Parse-and-retrieve-data-from-Excel-XLS-files.html).

```
$SimpleXLSX = new SimpleXLSX($filename);
$data = $SimpleXLSX->rows();
```

the $data is empty

this library work if I create an excel file by self using MS Excel.
if I try to get file content by using

```
print_r(file_get_contents($filename));
```

It return the content with HTML code

Like

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Gate Name</td>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Rank</td>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>Entry Type</td>
                <td>Work Place</td>
                <td>Car Type</td>
                <td>Car Number</td>
                <td>Inspector Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gate 2</td>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>فارس الغامدي</td>
                <td>ملازم اول</td>
                <td>28/02/1435 07:01:00</td>
                <td>دخول</td>
                <td>قطاع رفحاء</td>
                <td>جيب</td>
                <td>Tuy 124</td>
                <td>عبدالله</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I think the problem is with header() function or encoding when Creating Excel file.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't export a Excel file, you simply export a HTML table as a file with a .xls extension. It cannot be re-imported as a Excel file.

Comment: @MathieuImbert So who to make it proper MS Excel file when exporting?

Comment: use the PHPExcel class in the Pear library. Its much more extensible.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXLSX will read XLSX files and print HTML code, but you cannot convert HTML code to XLSX format using SimpleXLSX. Here's an example of how to do it in PHPExcel:

```
<?php


$date = date("m-d-Y-g-i-s");

// Include and instantiate PHPExcel object.
include '../lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
include '../lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set metadata.
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Price List $date");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("$date Price List");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("The active price list for $date.");

// Set active sheet index at zero.
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Determine limit and offset.
if($_GET['limit'] > 0 && $_GET['offset'] > 0) {
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];
} else {
    $limit = 10000;
    $offset = 0;
}

// Query the database.
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` LIMIT $offset, $limit") or die(mysql_error());
$c = 0; // Initialize index at zero.

// Set column dimensions.
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);

// Loop through data and insert it into their respective columns.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $c++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A$c")->setValueExplicit(stripslashes($row[strStock]), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B$c", stripslashes(html_entity_decode($row[strDescription])));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C$c", stripslashes($row[curPrice]));
}

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Send headers to download XLSX file.
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

if(isset($_GET[part]) && isset($_GET[of])) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Price List (Part '.$_GET[part].' of '.$_GET[of].') '.$date.'.xlsx"');
}

header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');exit;

?>
```

Edit: Sorry, this is the code for PHPExcel, not SimpleXLSX. [Here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/documentation) is the documentation for PHPExcel.

Comment: @josh I am using Codeinitor How can be use this with Codeinitor ?